# jQuery, select attribute from an input while looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to pull an attribute value from the input

This is some of my html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="invoice" client="14" value="53">
<input type="checkbox" name="invoice" client="14" value="54">
<input type="checkbox" name="invoice" client="17" value="52">
```

But I can't seem to be able to select anything, everytime I try to use a function while I'm eaching through them, is throwing undefined function

```
var inputs = $('input[name=invoice]');
    inputs.each(function(){
        console.log(this.attr('client'));
    });

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

while if I say `this.value` it returns 53, 54 and 52

Comment: You made a typo, use `$(this)` instead of `this` . You want to access the jQuery element, not the dom element which have not the .attr method

Comment: `this === HTMLElement`, `.attr() === jQuery method`. HTMLElement doesnt have access to the jQuery method. Use `$(this).attr('client')`

Comment: Awesome, that's it, didn't knew that!

Comment: All jQuery variable are written with a $

Comment: Also `this.getAttribute('client')`

Comment: Can I also ask why `$('input[name="invoice"]').get(0).attr('client')` doesn't work either?

Comment: `.get(0)` returns the `HTMLElement` at `0`th index...

Comment: Seems like someone didn't read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/each/, http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: @Mazzy in jQuery, use [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the jQuery element at the given index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) is a jQuery method. `this` inside [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) refers to the native HTML element. You should make it a jquery object for calling jQuery methods like `$(this).attr('client')`

Comment: Already said in comment, already tried by OP, are you trying to get easy points ?

Comment: @Superdrac Questions should not be answered in comments, that means they'll be left unanswered, new users will keep coming to it thinking the question is unanswered... Comments are meant for different purpose.

Comment: Both of you are right, question should be answered but when someone answered the question in the comment (and it work) you should A) Let him answer and get the point or B) Answer it yourself and checking the `community wiki` on the bottom right of the answer box. **Related :** http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon There is hardly 1 or two minutes difference between the comment and my answer. It could be due to the network issues, or the captcha. Do you seriously think I couldn't answer this by myself..?

Comment: @Superdrac Knowing that this question is a duplicate, I would either find the duplicate or make it community because it is really easy points.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon true ! Need to find the duplicate subject now.

Comment: @TJ i'm not saying anything like that, i'm just stating the fact and answering your both first comments. In case thing like this happen again, well now you know what you have to do. Just so you know, if superdrac had made an answer, it would've probably be the one being accepted because it is the comment that helped the OP first. Well, we could go on a debate that, but now im on a quest to find a duplicate!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I quit that quest [after reading this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/). I don't think it's worth the time.

Comment: @TJ TLDR; im sorry ahah! But I quit this quest when i couldn't find one on the first page on google. Here, have an upvote but i would really like to see that question a community wiki ;)